# Cordova turial handlebars.js blank screen

Tags: javascript, cordova, handlebars.js

I am following this Cordova [tutorial](https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/handlebars-templates.html).

I am in handlebars.js tutorial and when I run it on my device I get blank white screen. Can you help spot what is missing on the code?

This is index html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link href="assets/ratchet/css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script id="home-tpl" type="text/template">
            <header class="bar bar-nav">
                <h1 class="title">Directory</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="bar bar-standard bar-header-secondary">
                <input class='search-key' type="search"/>
            </div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </script>

        <script id="employee-list-tpl" type="text/template">
            <ul class="table-view">
                {{#each this}}
                    <li class="table-view-cell media">
                        <a href="#employees/{{ id }}">
                            <img class="media-object pull-left" src="assets/pics/{{pic}}">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
                                <p>{{title}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </script>

        <script src="lib/handlebars.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/localstorage/EmployeeService.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/fastclick.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the App.Js

```
// We use an "Immediate Function" to initialize the application to avoid leaving anything behind in the global scope
(function() {

    /* ---------------------------------- Local Variables ---------------------------------- */
    var service = new EmployeeService();
    var homeTpl = Handlebars.compile($("#home-tpl").html());
    var employeeListTpl = Handlebars.compile("#employee-list-tpl").html());
    service.initialize().done(function() {
        renderHomeView();
    });

    /* --------------------------------- Event Registration -------------------------------- */
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        if (navigator.notification) { // Override default HTML alert with native dialog
            window.alert = function(message) {
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    message,    // message
                    null,       // callback
                    "Workshop", // title
                    'OK'        // buttonName
                );
            };
        }

        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    }, false);

    /* ---------------------------------- Local Functions ---------------------------------- */
    function findByName() {
        service.findByName($('.search-key').val()).done(function (employees) {
            $('.content').html(employeeListTpl(employees));
        });
    }

    function renderHomeView() {
        $('body').html(homeTpl());
        $('.search-key').on('keyup', findByName);
    }

}());
```

Comment: if you import app.js at the end.

Comment: Still the same even if I imported app.js at the end

Comment: if you test at the browser, it's rendered well?

Comment: I already found the correct code here https://gist.github.com/xfry/11e79d65ccb00900ab72. Thanks for trying to help!